# ReactJS Date Validation Failing on Server - Symfony4 Azure/nginx

Tags: reactjs, azure, nginx, symfony4

This one is driving me nuts.

I have a ReactJS app wired up to a Symfony4 Rest API. I'm making a basic PUT request. All was working well until recently - now any form containing a date value fails validation on the date element

When I replicate the request locally using MAMP/Postman, it works perfectly. Exact same codebase. However the exact same code deployed on the Azure server (CentOS/nginx) throws the error.

What could be causing this? I guess the question is: What could be different config wise between a local Apache server and an Azure cloud server running nginx, both running the same code.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**Request Header**

`Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/admin/offers/standard/6/edit
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36`

**Request Body**

`{
    "notes": "SOME NOTES - Offer first draft",
    "po_number": "1234567",
    "company_id": 13,
    "start_date": "2018-12-09"
    }`

**Symfony Form:**

```
`->add('start_date', DateType::class, [
'invalid_message' => 'Please enter a valid date with time for post date: 
Y-M-d',
'widget' => 'single_text',
'format' => 'Y-M-d',
        ])`
```

Comment: I strongly think that it's some kind of timezone/date config discrepancy between the two servers...

Comment: The validation message is asking for the date to include a time, but it doesn’t look like a time is being sent with the date. Could be that?

Comment: Thanks @DougProctor I will give that a try now.